# Yodleee Exception "CoreExceptionFaultMessage"

Tags: yodlee

I tried to get transactions from over 100 accounts everyday using yodlee .NET API. And they were working well for a long time. But since yesterday a lot of accounts got the exception "CoreExceptionFaultMessage". I tried to run the failed accounts several times, sometime it worked, sometime it got that exception.

This problem once happened about one month ago and I posted it on Yodlee forums, but got no feedback.

I will really appreciate it if somebody can help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on the number of accounts one user can add.

We had a issue with Chase bank few days back and SDK was returning "CoreExceptionFaultMessage" for all the items which belonged to chase site. We have fixed the issue.

Can you validate if you are still getting the error?
If yes, can you please log a request using YCC providing request /response of such items which fails with "CoreExceptionFaultMessage".